# Repeated vs. Intermittent use of the GIL

Tags: python, python-c-extension, gil

Have there been any comparisons done on acquiring/releasing the GIL frequently vs. sparingly?

For example, take the [`keywdarg_parrot` function defined here](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html#keyword-parameters-for-extension-functions). If a developer wanted to be cognizant of the other threads that may require the GIL, they could re-write it as:

```
static PyObject *
keywdarg_parrot(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *keywds)
{
    int voltage;
    char *state = "a stiff";
    char *action = "voom";
    char *type = "Norwegian Blue";

    static char *kwlist[] = {"voltage", "state", "action", "type", NULL};

    if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, keywds, "i|sss", kwlist,
                                     &voltage, &state, &action, &type))
        return NULL;

    Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS

    printf("-- This parrot wouldn't %s if you put %i Volts through it.\n", action, voltage);
    printf("-- Lovely plumage, the %s -- It's %s!\n", type, state);

    Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS

    Py_INCREF(Py_None);    
    return Py_None;
}
```

Afterall, the GIL isn't *needed* to use `printf`, so why let `keywdarg_parrot` bogart it? Now imagine these micro-GIL-acquisitions everywhere else in the C-library. Is it best to release the GIL at any & every chance you get, or is it the case that the less is more?